# Change create.objectURL for HTMLMediaElement.srcObject

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, model-view-controller

When adding the class createObjectURL it is accusing deprecated error in some browsers, after searches I verified that I can use the HTMLMediaElement. But how can I include it in my project?

```
export class CameraController {

    constructor(videoEl){

        this._videoEl = videoEl;

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video:true
        }).then(stream=>{

        this._stream = stream;
        this._videoEl.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        this.videoEl.play(); 

        }).catch(err=>{
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

    stop(){

        this._stream.getTracks().forEach(track=>{
            track.stop();
        });
    }

    takePicture(mimeType = 'image/png'){

        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas.setAttribute('height', this._videoEl.videoHeight);
        canvas.setAttribute('width', this._videoEl.videoWidth);

        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.drawImage(this._videoEl, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        return canvas.toDataURL(mimeType);

    }
}
```

how can I change to HTMLelement?

Comment: Please, add more details.

Comment: Sorry,I just corrected it.